# Elasticsearch aggregations facet filter

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I already make facet search with elasticsearch aggregations. Term aggregation returned "doc_count" of each bucket. I want to create facet like this:

Letters:
-a (22)
-b (33)
-c (44)

And when I put mark on line c I want to get something like this

Letters:
-a (+22)
-b (+33)
*c (44)

Thanks for your advice